# Is it possible for an opponent to have zero deadwood when I gin?

Tags: gin-rummy

While playing Gin on an app, I knocked with gin and my opponent showed zero deadwood. Given I had gin, my opponent was unable to play any cards on mine; so, is it possible for a player to have zero deadwood if the opponent knocks with gin?

Answer (score 1):

**Possible, but unlikely.**  It means that your opponent chose to discard when he had Gin.  There is no good reason to do this.

Other explanations:

1. If both players are dealt a gin hand (very rare).
2. A misclick.
3. An opponent that do not know the rules.
4. A bad AI agent.
5. In games where the Undercut bonus is larger than the Gin bonus then in some rare cases it might be better to try undercutting instead of making a Gin.
6. The opponent run out of time, thus an auto-move was played.